# SQL PaaS Network Security Configuration

Tags: networking, azure

We have a bastion host on which we have configured network security groups. The purpose is to connect with SQL PaaS using management studio. For the NSG tied to the bastion host we have defined two outbound rules:
1000 SQLConnect Any Internet 1433 Allow
4000 DefaultOutb Any Internet All ports Deny

I am not able to connect to SQL PaaS from the bastion host. When i delete the 4000 rule i can connect. As NSG is stateless, I am trying to figure out why this is not working. Any help I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a by design behavior, after you defined two outbound rules, the NSG will just allow port 1433 to traffic out, other ports will deny.
Which version of Azure SQL database are you using? If your SQL version is V12, you need to allow other ports in the outbound rules.

When your client runs inside the Azure cloud boundary, it uses what we can call a direct route to interact with the SQL Database server. After a connection is established, further interactions between the client and database involve no middleware proxy.

> Ensure that the port ranges of 11000-11999 and 14000-14999 on your
>   Azure client machine are left available for ADO.NET 4.5 client
>   interactions with SQL Database V12.
>   In particular, ports in the range must be free of any other outbound
>   blockers.

More information about the connection behavior of clients that use ADO.NET 4.5 or a later version, please refer to the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-develop-direct-route-ports-adonet-v12).